# Using R in Sublime text 3: independent help page

Tags: r, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimerepl

In R (just default mac R) on my mac machine, when I see the help page with

```
> ?read.csv
```

it appears on a new window with a beautiful format.

Now I'm using the Sublime text 3 for R (with SublimeREPL:R, R-Box, R-Extended etc.) on the mac machine, many things work fine.

My question is:
when I type the help page (`?read.csv`), the contents appear on the same ST3 window with a plain format.
Is there any way to make it appear on a new window such as a HTML page (in Safari)?

Comment: Yep I agree thanks. But I tested the same thing with ST3 on Windows 10. In this case the help page was shown on IE. So I'm wondering whether this case might be possible on the mac machine.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `help_type` option to `"html"`:

```
options(help_type = 'html')
```

and it will open help files in the default browser. If you put that in your `.Rprofile`, you won't need to set it for each session.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! That said, I highly recommend RStudio; it's just a much better cross-platform editor for R that will scale with you more naturally. It's not that heavy in size or resources either, so there are very few reasons not to use it.